Confusion on optimizing variable time-offset for VIO SLAM
I was reading the following paper on how you can incorporate variable time offset for a camera in VIO:
https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Yonggen_Ling_Modeling_Varying_Camera-IMU_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf
As far as I understand the paper is optimizing camera-image time offset and not IMU time offset.
What I am confused on is how the jacobian of the image residual is computed with respect to time.
I'm clearly missing something as normally the image jacobian should be time-independent(IE SFM does not consider time as a variable as there isn't a motion model associated with it).
So what's going on? I guess I don't understand what they are doing.
